# SQL Server MDX query parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I am very new to MDX query. I am trying to pass a parameter through my query. It is giving me this SQL error:

> *Query preparation failed.*
>   *The function expects a tuple expression for the 5 argument.*
>   *A tuple set expression was used.*

The query is:

```
SELECT 
{
[Measures].[DENOMINATOR]
,[Measures].[NUMERATOR]
,[Measures].[Goal]
}
ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
(
 [Dim Indicator].[Indicator Set].[Indicator Set].ALLMEMBERS
 ,[Dim Indicator].[Indicator Group].[Indicator Group].ALLMEMBERS
 ,[Dim Indicator].[Indicator Name].[Indicator Name].ALLMEMBERS
)
ON ROWS
FROM [Dummy-Dashboard]

--Parameter Queries goes here 

WHERE 
(
    strtoset(@DimGenderGenderID)
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to test you query with parameter you will need to use XMLA for that. Please see below example for xmla:

```
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <Body>
        <Execute xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
          <Command>
            <Statement>
              Your code in here
            </Statement>
          </Command>
          <Properties>
            <PropertyList xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
              <DataSourceInfo>Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=local;</DataSourceInfo>
              <Catalog>CubeName</Catalog>
              <Format>Tabular</Format>
              <Content>Data</Content>
              <Timeout>0</Timeout>
            </PropertyList>
          </Properties>
          <Parameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
            <Parameter>
              <Name>ParameterName</Name>
              <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">ParameterValue</Value>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
        </Execute>
      </Body>
    </Envelope>
```